# Can I loop this?

Tags: excel, while-loop, vba

Having a heck of a time looping this; D2 is where the list starts. I would like to have it ran for d3, d4, d5, d6.... until a blank space.

Also, I will be placing the data into column E and that would need to also increase like column D; e2,e3,e4,e5,e6...

```
Sub james() 'Main Program
Dim celltxt As String
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value

DELETE_EJ

If InStr(1, celltxt, "Christy", vbTextCompare) Then
    Range("E2").Value = "Christy"

ElseIf InStr(1, celltxt, "Kari", vbTextCompare) Then
    Range("E2").Value = "Kari"

ElseIf InStr(1, celltxt, "Sue", vbTextCompare) Then
    Range("E2").Value = "Sue"

ElseIf InStr(1, celltxt, "Clayton", vbTextCompare) Then
    Range("E2").Value = "Clayton"
```

Comment: `Having a heck of a time looping` because you have no loop at all?

Comment: @findwindow you're on a roll today ;)

Comment: @mrbungle lol just stating the obvious XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, define a range to loop over, and then you can do it like this using an inner loop over the list of names:

```
Sub foo() 'Main Program

Dim nmArr()
Dim i as Long
Dim loopRange as Range
Dim cl As Range

'## This is the range you will loop over
Set loopRange = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D6") '## Modify as needed

'## This is the list of names built as an array
nmArr = Array("Christy", "Kari", "Sue", "Clayton")

DELETE_EJ

For Each cl in loopRange.Cells
    For i = LBound(nmArr) to Ubound(nmArr)
        If Instr(1, cl.Value, nmArr(i), vbTextCompare) Then
            cl.Offset(0,1).Value = nmArr(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next 

End Sub
```

Above requires hardcoding the range, but if you need to just do it *until it finds a blank cell*, then modify like so:

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo() 'Main Program

Dim nmArr()
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

Set cl = ActiveSheet.Range("D2") '## This is the STARTING cell

'## This is the list of names built as an array
nmArr = Array("Christy", "Kari", "Sue", "Clayton")

DELETE_EJ

Do

    For i = LBound(nmArr) To UBound(nmArr)
        If InStr(1, cl.Value, nmArr(i), vbTextCompare) Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = nmArr(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    '## Get a handle on the NEXT cell
    Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
Loop Until Trim(cl.Text) = vbNullString

End Sub
```

Second approach has been tested & working to produce outputs like:

[image]

Comment: I am getting a compile error End If without Block If?

Comment: Sorry, the second `End If` *should* be a `Next`. I'll revise :)

Comment: Now RunTime Error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set? Where can I read up on something like this?? I really appreciate your help @davidzemens

Comment: I also had a typo in the loop using `j` instead of `i`. I think that is fixed now, but let me know if you're still getting the 91 error, and which line is causing it.

Comment: Doesnt indicate which one, normally it highlights in yellow but not in this case

Comment: Step through the code using F8 key until the error happens?

Comment: @JSt `Where can I read up on something` try [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299036).

Comment: If InStr(1, cl.Value, nmArr(i), vbTextCompare) Then [highlights] then the next f8 retrieves the error.

Comment: Found it, and fixed it. `cl` had not been assigned anything. Revised to not use the `loopRange` variable at all in the second approach, it should be working now.

Comment: Wish I could upvote more than once just because of the work you just went through.

Comment: @ScottCraner it would've been less work for me if I had just run it through the compiler before posting the answer hahaha :D

Comment: That exactly did it. Thank you so much. Now I will add 5 more columns to extract data and use this formatting to keep going. Only been writing VBA for 2 weeks. Its rather enjoyable.  Seriously, thank you again.

Comment: I got you @ScottCraner

Comment: Heres a tricky one, now what if I wanted to do the same thing in column E as in Column F but the program would check Column E and wouldnt place the same name in E as it would move to F??

Comment: Not sure I follow, and it sounds like the scope of that follow-up is probably better suited for a new question, as it may be too much to try and describe in the comments section here...

Comment: Basically if there are 2 names in D, one goes in E and the other in F, I will repost this in another question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, put the names in an array then loop through the array.:

```
Sub james() 'Main Program
Dim celltxt As String
Dim nmArr()

nmArr = Array("Christy", "Kari", "Sue", "Clayton")
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value

DELETE_EJ
For i = LBound(nmArr) To UBound(nmArr)
    If InStr(1, celltxt, nmArr(i), vbTextCompare) Then
        Range("E2").Value = nmArr(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that works much better than having all that code with the names listed individually. How can I get that D2 and E2 to loop to run the row under? D3 info to E3??

Comment: @JSt see David's answer.  I missed the second loop.

Comment: Thanks @scottcramer!